# What does "each time out" mean?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

Can you please tell me what ***each time out*** means. I've come across the phrase in this [video](https://youtu.be/JTjg4PFPWrA) around 6 minutes and 44 seconds. Here is the sentence it was used in:

> ...and they still made three more films, a TV show, and an animated show in the original film universe. Each has a political theme or a lesson they are tackling, and they construct a new and exciting story around that theme **each time out**.

I've looked up this phrase on the internet, but there were no results. Without the ***out***, the sentence makes perfect sense. I'd like to know what ***out*** adds to the meaning and how you would rephrase it.

Comment: I think it's unnecessary, here.

Comment: *...each time **they put another** [film or TV show] out*. It's not a "common, idiomatic" construction, but I don't think many native Anglophones would give it a second thought. Don't assume my "syntactically valid reconstruction" represents any kind of "original, uncontracted" version of the text, though. You could just as well deconstruct it as "short for" *each time they **set out** [start] to write another screenplay*.

Comment: When you link to a youtube video, it's possible to include the time in the video like so: https://youtu.be/JTjg4PFPWrA?si=q9eqZi793pMVKO9G&t=403

You can select this option when you click "share"

Comment: It's just fast speech and not very well said. Each time they set out to do something, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Each time out** means each time they come out with a new film or show.

When a new movie or TV show is released, it's very common to use **come out** to describe that. For example:

> There's a new episode coming out on Tuesday.
> The newest James Bond movie comes out this week.
> When they come out with a movie worth seeing, I'll go to the movie theater.

So **each time out** means **each time they come out** with a new project.

As you noted, **out** is not required, but it does potentially add meaning to the sentence. For example, if they created a new film, but they kept it for themselves and never released it to the public, you might say **each time** instead of **each time out,** since one of the films never actually came out.